# Compiling React into Static Files

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a web app with the frontend done in react, and I was wondering if it's possible to compile my react code into static HTML and JS files to be used with any server. So far I've been using the server run with

```
npm start
```

but for my final project I need to use a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
npm run build
```

This command creates a built version of your application in the *build* folder

Answer (score 0):

Static builds are a standard in react deploying pipelines. You have to setup a build pipeline with webpack configuring it for minification assets management and so on.