# 404 Error when deploying React App on custom domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, github-pages

It seems like I followed all the necessary in the documentation but it keeps giving a 404 Error: "There isn't a GitHub pages here" when I go into https://juliesong.me. 
I got my custom domain through GoDaddy and configured the DNS like so:
[image]

Then I changed my `package.json` file to have

```
"homepage": "https://www.juliesong.me",
```

Added a CNAME file in the root directory containing
`www.juliesong.me`

And lastly went into settings in GitHub pages:
[image]

I searched my issue up and a lot of people said it might have to do with the React Router, so I edited to include a basename:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const routing = (
  <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <App />
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import { GlobalStyles, } from "./util/GlobalStyles";

import Home from './containers/Home'


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const home = () => <Home />

    return (
      <main>
        <GlobalStyles />
          <React.Fragment>
              <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
          </React.Fragment>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

If anyone could help on this issue, that would be great:)

Comment: Have you pushed anything to the branch `gh-pages`?

Comment: @ksav could you elaborate on this? I'm not sure exactly what you mean on this.

Comment: I guess your project is missing an index.html but even if you had one; github.io is a static file server so if you use routes like `yoursite/my/info` then it will give a 404 because there is no such file called `my/info/index`. What needs to go to github.io is not the react project itself but the result of a build of that project.

Comment: Could you add how are you deploying it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one
add new file named .htaccess in your build folder
[example of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIdDk.jpg)
and add this code into your .htaccess file
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz9XZ.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you share how you are generating the build and pushing it to GitHub Pages, it is very difficult to identify the cause of this issue.

Still let me share a general way you would deploy a react app in GitHub pages.

- You don't need to add `basename` in your router
- Good thing is you are using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`, because GitHub pages doesn't support history api like normal browser, it will look for a specific file in given path
- To deploy your app you need to run the following command in same order -

```
npm run build # this will generate a build folder
```

```
gh-pages -d build # this will publish the build folder to GitHub pages
```

- 

> This is very important that you publish the `build` folder, because
> its contains the `index.html` file, which GitHub will point.

- 

You can read more about deploying react app to GitHub Pages [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

React-app out of the box is client-server application, and you should compile it first to html + client side js before deploying.

There are lots of good docs: [create-react-app.dev](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/pre-rendering-into-static-html-files/), [medium.com](https://siddharthac6.medium.com/getting-started-with-react-js-using-webpack-and-babel-66549f8fbcb8) and [the shortest way here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709675/compiling-react-into-static-files/51709758)